# Counting nested association objects in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to return counts for associated objects in my ember controller.

I have:

```
App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    discussion: DS.belongsTo('App.Discussion')
});

App.Discussion = DS.Model.extend({
    meeting: DS.belongsTo('App.Meeting'),
    comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')
});

App.Meeting = DS.Model.extend({
    discussions: DS.hasMany('App.Discussion')
});
```

Now in my Meeting controller I want to return counts for the discussions and comments associated with that meeting:

```
App.MeetingController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    discussionCount: function(){
        return this.get('discussions.length');
    }.property('discussions')
});
```

I can get discussions fine, but I can't find a way to get the associated comments of the discussions associated with each meeting. Any ideas how it is best to do this?

Comment: you should not need to convert your `ManyArray`

    App.MeetingController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
        discussionCount: function(){
            return this.get('discussions.length');
        }.property('discussions')
    });

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the example. Any help with the nested association?

Comment: testing something ;-)

Comment: I thought something like this would work, but no joy:     commentCount: function() {
        var counter = 0;
        this.get('discussions').forEach(function(d) {
            counter += d.get('comments.length');
        });
        return counter;}.property('discussions.@each.comments')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how many discussions and comments you have, but this is typical of the n+1 select problem (see [What is SELECT N+1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue) ).

There is a real risk for performance issue.

If you don't think it's a problem, you can create a filter on the `itemController` to get all the comments associated to a meeting, and then use this array to compute the total count.

Otherwise you can cache the number of comments on a discussion server-side and add this counter to the `App.Discussion` model.